# Save JSON Data In Cache

Tags: ios, uitableview, caching, saving-data

I am working on a project that has a TableView which loads the contents of a JSON file on my server. Everything works correctly, but I have two problems.

1) When I change the View and load a different View, when I came back to this TableView ... the TableView tries to re-load the contents, there is no errors, but the progress bar appears briefly. How to avoid this from happening?

2) My second problem is that, once loaded, if I lose the internet connection and change the View, the content gets lost. Even I already downloaded.
How would I do the cache of this information?

Here is the code:

```
@interface ProgramacaoTableViewController ()
{
    // Object thats hold the content
    MProgramacao *_programacao;
}

    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // TS MESSAGE
    [TSMessage setDefaultViewController:self];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];

    // Add Refresh Control
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

    ////
    // Check Connection and Load Data
    if ([self IsConnected]) {

        // YES INTERNET
        // show loader view
        [ProgressHUD show:@"Loading.."];

        // fetch the feed
        _programacao = [[MProgramacao alloc] initFromURLWithString:@"http://myurl..."
                                                        completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {

                                                            //hide the loader view
                                                            [ProgressHUD dismiss];

                                                            //json fetched
                                                            [self.tableView reloadData];

                                                        }];


    }
    else {
        // NO INTERNET
        [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error Message", nil)
                                    subtitle:NSLocalizedString(@"try again", nil)
                                        type:TSMessageNotificationTypeError];

    }

}
```

I edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should **download the data just in the** `viewDidLoad`, and then when the user **WANT**, he can **pull the tableView to refresh**. This is the correct way.

In this way, your `tableView` will **remains loaded** also when you push a `viewController` and then come back, and your *"temporary cache"* is your array `_programacao`.

If you want store the data also in case you close the app, you could use for example `CoreData`, but this is another thing that is not necessary for your purpose.

Comment: This TableView **opens** my App. **Is the first view that appears**. Anyway should I use on viewdidload?

Comment: Exactly. DidLoad is called just the first time that you open your viene controller, ie when finish to load the view frame.

Comment: So I tried but it doesn't work here.
I put the code that **was in viewDidAppear** in my **viewDidLoad**. But if I lose the internet connection, the content that was downloaded before no longer appears. I have to change something in the code?

Comment: I dont understand your problem: if now there is the connection and you load the tableview, also if in a second moment the connection there isn't, the tableview remains loaded until you don't dealloc its viewController. It means that if you form the viewController of the tableview, present another viewController and then come back, the tableView continue to be loaded.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. but it's not happening.
Maybe the View, after I load the content, go to another view e come back.
The TableView tries to load of new content, as there is no connection, the content is gone.
I wonder if I should check if my array _programacao has some content? If so, the code does nothing, if not, it tries to download the content.

Comment: Now i don't know What you are doing when you change view. Post the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54458/discussion-between-diego-rodrigues-and-matteo-gobbi).